# ModelState.IsValid is false but should be true

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with AJAX updating. CRUD operations for every entity are working correctly, except for creating a "Receipt". The problem arises when the controller hits `ModelState.IsValid` which translates to false when in fact it should be true. I debugged everything step by step so many times, and it is always false when it should be true.

I am using Entity Framework for entity manipulation and this is the code that was generated from the SQL Server database:

```
public partial class Receipt
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Receipt()
    {
        this.Receipts1 = new HashSet<Receipt>();
        this.Seminars = new HashSet<Seminar>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PaymentDue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ClosedReceiptId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ReturnedAmount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> ReturnTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Receipt> Receipts1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Receipt Receipt1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ReturnType ReturnType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Seminar> Seminars { get; set; }
}
```

On top of which I have `ReceiptMetadata` for annotations and `[Required]` fields:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ReceiptMetadata))]
public partial class Receipt
{
}

public class ReceiptMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Issue Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:G}")]
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Payment Due")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? PaymentDue { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Return amount")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public Nullable<decimal> ReturnedAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And my `Create` function in controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,IssueDate,DeliveryDate,PaymentDue,CompanyId,Number")]Receipt receipt, int? seminarId)
{
    if (seminarId == null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { Message = "ID is required" });
    }

    Seminar seminar = db.Seminars.Find(seminarId);

    if (seminar == null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { Message = "Seminar doesn't exist" });
    }

    int receiptNumber = db.Receipts.Where(r => r.CompanyId == receipt.CompanyId && r.ClosedReceiptId == null && r.IssueDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Count() + 1;
    receipt.Number = receiptNumber;
    receipt.IssueDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Central European Standard Time");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Receipts.Add(receipt);
            db.SaveChanges();

            seminar.ReceiptId = receipt.Id;
            db.Entry(seminar).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();

            GeneratePDF(receipt.Id, receipt.ReceiptNumber, receipt.CompanyId.ToString());
            return Json(new { receipt.Id, receipt.PDFLink, Action = "Create", Message = "Receipt successfully added! -> " }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();

    foreach (ModelError error in allErrors)
    {
        errorMessages.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return Json(new { Message = errorMessages });
}
```

The error I get is

> The Number field is required.

when clearly the field `Number` is filled in with:

```
receipt.Number = receiptNumber;
```

a few lines before the `IsValid`.

Can someone please help?

**EDIT**: this is a screenshot from debugging, the modelstate keys are completely wrong:

[image: Debugging image]

Comment: I think that the value for IsValid and the whole ModelState is calculated before any change you make in your controller code. Too late!

Comment: I believe `ModelState` records the state of your model as at when you post the data. You should make the property `Nullable`.

Comment: What my concern is that as you can see from the ReceiptMetadata "IssueDate" is also Required and is put right after the Number, but it doesn't arise any errors. I updated the main question with the image of ModelState errors in debug mode, which is very weird and shows wrong keys as they should be "PaymentDue", "IssueDate" and "Number", not "CompanyId" or "seminarId" which is just a helper attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ModelState is already evaluated (and invalid) when entering your action, setting the "Number" property won't evaluate the model again. After setting the property, you may have to manually remove it from the model errors by writing this:

```
ModelState.Remove("Number");
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. But I'm still wondering why are my ModelState keys displaying incorrectly, missing Issue Date which is Required in my Metadata

Comment: IssueDate is DateTime in your model and if you check the value using the debugger it will probably have the min datetime value: Jan 1, 0001. May sound weird but if you want to make it Required and check null values, try changing it to "DateTime?"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a long time and finally I found it. In my case, it was the Id field :)

Just place a breakpoint and check your ModelState in runtime and go to this section :

ModelState -> Root -> Children

and you will see all valid and invalid Keys

[image]