# Asp.Net MVC ModelState is not valid why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a following Designer model:

```
public class Designer
{
    [HiddenInput]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Profile picture is required")]
    public string ProfilePictureUrl { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Full name is required")]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength =3,ErrorMessage ="Full name must be between 3 and 25 chars")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bio")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Biography is required")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<Designer_Clothes> Designer_Clothes { get; set; }
}
```

Designer controller:

```
 public class DesignerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDesignerService _service;

    public DesignerController(IDesignerService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var data = await _service.GetAll();
        return View(data);
    }
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("FullName,ProfilePictureUrl,Bio")] Designer designer)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _service.Add(designer);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        return View();
        
    }
}
```

And the View:

```
<div class="row text">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <p>
            <h1>Add a New Designer</h1>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                <form asp-action="Create">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <img id="ProfilePicturePreview" class="border-info rounded-circle" style="max-width: 150px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ProfilePictureUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ProfilePictureUrl" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ProfilePictureUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Bio" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Bio" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Bio" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" />
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="Index">Show All</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i try to add a new record to database i can't do that becouse modelstate is not valid Why?
I have no errors

Following line:
public List<Designer_Clothes> Designer_Clothes { get; set; }
is a relation to other table

I tried to delete required lines from model and problem still happening

Comment: Not all required fields are filled.

Comment: what about the list? Is it optional?

Comment: List is a relation to other table (junction table)

Comment: Please post code samples as code, not as images

Comment: @JohnM I post the code

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840344/5976413) tip may help

Comment: @JohnM in my case this line: public List<Designer_Clothes> Designer_Clothes { get; set; } is invalid

Comment: You may need to add a constructor to your Designer class that initializes the Designer_Clothes property to an empty list

Comment: But this line is a navigation to another table

Comment: Hi @Ptrk12, any update here?

Comment: @Rena i just add "?" public List<Designer_Clothes> Designer_Clothes { get; set; } to this line and that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `.NET 6`/`.NET 7`. From `.NET 6` the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **the first way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The second way**, you can initialize the model like below:

```
public class Designer
{
    //...
    public List<Designer_Clothes> Designer_Clothes { get; set; }= new List<Designer_Clothes>();
}
```

**The third way**, you can add `?` to allow nullable:

```
public class Designer
{
    //...
    public List<Designer_Clothes>? Designer_Clothes { get; set; }
}
```